# How well will Elementary OS run on a 5-yr old Acer netbook?

Tags: performance

How well will Elementary OS run on a 5-yr old Acer Aspire one 523h-2527 netbook?

Windows 7 runs very sluggishly. Would Elementary run faster?

Shortly after I bought it, I was advised by a knowledgeable person not to install Windows XP because drivers would not be available? Would be any any driver issues with Elementary?

Comment: Without a specific model or specifications, any answer is primarily speculation.

Comment: You'll most likely be fine. I'm running freya on an early 2008 MacBook (Intel Core2Duo 2,4 GHz CPU, 2GB RAM,  Intel GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller), and it actually works very fluently, even better than the original Mac OS 10.6.8 on the same machine. I don't know about the drivers, but given that your netbook is rather old there shouldn't be many problems. Give it a shot, I'd say it's worth it :)

Answer (score 1):

The [System Recommendations](https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#recommended-system-specifications) are: 
    Intel i3 or comparable dual-core 64-bit processor
    1 GB of system memory (RAM)
    15 GB of disk space
    Internet access

That being said: I run freya on a Dell Laptop from 2003. While it is slow, it's still faster than anything but LXDE.

There is also a way you can [turn off animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnDkGQm7irE) in pantheon, which will speed up performance on older systems. That video is for Luna, but I am pretty sure it will work in Freya.